# Powershell: redirect output from "NET share" or "Remove-SmbShare"

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to delete all shares and store the output of the command in a variable

Hopefully you can help me!

How do I delete a share?

```
  Invoke-Expression "Remove-SmbShare -Force -Name $name"
```

or

```
  NET SHARE $name /delete
```

Thanks!

edit:

I know that I can redirect the output to a File, but I do want it to redirect it directly into a variable.

```
 NET SHARE i$ /delete *> "C:\workspace\output.txt"
```

Why do I want to delete shares via Powershell? 
Forced shares via company rules and I want to get rid of them directly after the login

Comment: Both should work (albeit using `Remove-SmbShare` via `Invoke-Expression` seems overly complicated). Why do you ask? (Please extend the question.)

Comment: Redirection of one command is pretty basic powershell knowledge and wide covered over the net.
Take a look at https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6 .

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking in the powershell section if you should use a executable or a commandlet the answer is pretty obvious: the commandlet.

Remove-SmbShare does not generate output for successful execution so you will have to work around that.

What you could do is something like this:

```
$names = "TestShare","TestShare2"
$success = @()
foreach($name in $names){
    try {
        Remove-SmbShare $name -force -Erroraction Stop
        $success += $true
    } catch {
        $success += $false
    }
}
```

Afterwards you will have two arrays with corresponding indexes. Alternatively you could also add a string to the success array like so `$success += "$name $true"` but you will figure that out on your own.